# Finding and Comparing Previous Rows to current value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dateset and I want to go back and see the previous value that has changed.

Sample Data:

```
 Group  Value        
   01    10
   01    10
   01    10
   02    5
   02    5
   02    15
   03    20
   03    25
   03    15
   03    15
```

Desired Output:

```
Group     Value    Previous_Value
 01         10                 
 01         10     
 01         10
 02         5
 02         5
 02         15          5 
 03         20
 03         25         20
 03         15         25
 03         15
```

I have imported pandas and numpy for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` before `groupby_shift`:

```
df['Previous_Value'] = (df.drop_duplicates(['Group', 'Value'])
                          .groupby('Group')['Value']
                          .shift().reindex(df.index))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Group  Value  Previous_Value
0      1     10             NaN
1      1     10             NaN
2      1     10             NaN
3      2      5             NaN
4      2      5             NaN
5      2     15             5.0
6      3     20             NaN
7      3     25            20.0
8      3     15            25.0
9      3     15             NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on consecutive difference between values of `Value` column (if there's a difference - takes the previous value):

```
df['Prev_value'] = (df.groupby('Group')['Value']
                    .transform(lambda x: np.where(x.diff().isin([0, np.nan]), 
                                                  np.nan, x.shift())))
```

---

```
   Group  Value  Prev_value
0      1     10         NaN
1      1     10         NaN
2      1     10         NaN
3      2      5         NaN
4      2      5         NaN
5      2     15         5.0
6      3     20         NaN
7      3     25        20.0
8      3     15        25.0
9      3     15         NaN
```